# How to activate virtualenv using PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv, python-venv

I made virtualenv called **bitcoin_notifications.py** and I'm going to activate it but:

```
PS C:\Users\piotr> bitcoin_notifications\activate.ps1
```

````
bitcoin_notifications\activate.ps1 : ```The module
'bitcoin_notifications' could not be loaded. For more information, run
'Import-Module bitcoin_notifications'.``` At line:1 char:1
+ bitcoin_notifications\activate.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bitcoin_notifications\activate.ps1:String) [],
CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
````

In the result shared before we read the module could not be loaded and if one wants more info to run another specific command.

Once I run it,

````
PS C:\Users\piotr> ```Import-Module bitcoin_notifications

Import-Module : The specified module 'bitcoin_notifications' was not
loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
directory.``` At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module bitcoin_notifications
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (bitcoin_notifications:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ```Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand```
````

we can understand there's no module in that directory. I just want to activate the virtualenv. How can I do that?

EDIT:
I was copying the method of creating new venv:

1. `pip install virtualenv`
2. `mkdir Environments`
3. `cd !$`
4. `virtualenv bitcoin_notifications`
5. `bitcoin_notifications\activate.ps1`

Comment: The error message indicates that the `bitcoin_notifications` module could not be found. Is the module installed correctly?

Comment: Honestly, I was copying the method of creating new venv:                                        
 1.   ```pip install virtualenv```              2.   ```mkdir Environments```  3.   ```cd !$```                 4.   ```virtualenv bitcoin_notifications```       5.  ```bitcoin_notifications\activate.ps1```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first lines from **activate.ps1** seem to mention the solution:

```
# This file must be dot sourced from PoSh; you cannot run it
# directly. Do this: . ./activate.ps1
```

So, the following should work (step 4 and 5 from your method — note that step 5 was missing the dot!):

```
virtualenv bitcoin_notifications
. .\bitcoin_notifications\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

NB: Your question mentions `venv` but actually is about `virtualenv`. Note that these are two similar but different tools. Also, in step 5 you were missing the "Scripts" part. Maybe that was a copy-paste error when writing the question, but make sure to include it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem using Windows 10.

So, initially installed Python 3.7 (adding to Path) and ensured pip was working

```
PS C:\foldername> pip
```

Then, ran the following commands to install virtualenv

```
PS C:\foldername> pip install --upgrade setuptools
PS C:\foldername> pip install ez_setup
PS C:\foldername> pip install virtualenv
```

Created a virtualenvs folder and got into it

```
PS C:\foldername> mkdir virtualenvs
PS C:\foldername> cd virtualenvs
```

Then, create the virtual environment *molecoder*

```
PS C:\foldername\virtualenvs> virtualenv molecoder
PS C:\foldername\virtualenvs> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

and tried to activate it

```
PS C:\foldername\virtualenvs> molecoder\Scripts\acivate
```

and got the following message

> molecoder\Scripts\acivate : The module 'molecoder' could not be
>   loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module molecoder'. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + molecoder\Scripts\acivate
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (molecoder\Scripts\acivate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule

In my case was because i wrote **acivate** instead of **activate**, so the following modification worked

```
PS C:\foldername\virtualenvs> molecoder\Scripts\activate
```

In your case you're trying to activate but activate is inside *envname/Scripts* , you're going to the wrong location.

To fix it you just need to run

```
PS C:\Users\piotr> bitcoin_notifications\Scripts\activate
```